# CommanderJS - Prompt for missing args/options

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-commander

I'm trying to implement prompting users for missing required args/mandatory options.

I thought I could use a preSubcommand hook, change `process.argv` with prompts, and then allow commander to parse the updated argv.

My hook gets executed before any exit however, After the complete of my hook's callback, I will get this error: `error: required option '--foo' not specified`.

It seems that parsing continues after the hook on the old process.argv.

For example `my-cli subcommand --foo bar` will work fine.
`my-cli subcommand` will prompt for `foo` and push it to `process.argv` inside the hook but then exit with the error above.

Any ideas? I tried to suppress this error with `exitOverride` and re-calling `parse` afterwards, but my callback is not being reached. Surrounding in try-catch doesn't work either.

Here's my code:

```
program
        .name('cli')
        .description('foo')
        .version(version, '-v, --version')
        .addCommand(sub)
        .hook('preSubcommand', async (program, subcommand) => {
            await promptForMissingArgs(program, subcommand);
            console.log('here');
            console.log(process.argv);
            program.parse(process.argv); // called again with correct process.argv but still exits
        })
        .exitOverride((exitCode) => {
            console.log(`Exiting with code ${exitCode.exitCode}`); // not reached
            //  if (exitCode.exitCode !== 0) {
            //     program.parse(process.argv);
            //  }
        });
    // parse command line arguments and execute command
    try {
        program.parse(process.argv);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('here'); // doesn't reach here
        console.error(error);
    }
```

From the docs I see this: `if the first arg is a subcommand call preSubcommand hooks pass remaining arguments to subcommand, and process same way`
https://github.com/tj/commander.js/blob/HEAD/docs/parsing-and-hooks.md

Is it because my hook is async?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to change process.argv, I was able to set options during `preSubcommand` hook. I was not able to find a way to change argument values so I settled with options.

@shadowspawn answer is also valid but I have multiple subcommands so I chose to keep my prompting in the shared `preSubcommand` hook rather than `preAction`. This also let me keep options as mandatory because they are not checked yet at this stage in the parsing lifecycle

```
import { Command } from 'commander';

const program = new Command();
const subcommand= new Command();

(async () => {
subcommand
  .option('-p, --port <number>')
  .action(async (options) => {
    console.log(options);
  });

program.addCommand(subcommand)
  .hook('preSubcommand', async (thisCommand, sub) => {
    await promptForMissingArgs(thisCommand, sub);
  })

await program.parseAsync();
})();
```

With `promptForMissingArgs` implementation something like this:

```
async function promptForMissingArgs(command, subcommand) {
  const answers = await inquirer.prompt(getMissingFromArgv(subcommand.opts()));
  Object.keys(answers).forEach(ans => subcommand.setOptionValue(ans, answers[ans]));
}

function getMissingFromArgv(opts) {
  // compare process.argv against mandatory opts() to see what is missing
  // return list of prompts for inquirer
}
```

Comment: An advantage of the `preAction` hook is you can check the parsed options without needing to parse process.argv yourself. Multiple subcommands is not a factor, both allow that. But being able to fall through to built-in mandatory option handling (i.e. `requiredOption()`) is an advantage of using `preSubcommand`.

Answer (score 0):

Commander does not support mutating the arguments to be parsed in the middle of parsing. Also, there isn't an easy place to inject last-minute processing before the check for mandatory options.

What you can easily do is prompt for missing options without marking them as mandatory as such. A simple place to prompt is at the start of the action handler, but a hook may allow code reuse or separate your logic better. Here is an example with a hook in the spirit of your code.

```js
import { Command } from 'commander';

const program = new Command();

program
  .option('-p, --port <number>')
  .hook('preAction', async (thisCommand) => {
    const options = thisCommand.opts();
    // Simulate prompting for and setting missing options.
    if (!options.port) {
      console.log('You forgot to specify a port number.');
      thisCommand.setOptionValue('port', '3000');
    }
  })
  .action(async (options) => {
    console.log(options);
  });

program.parseAsync();
```

```
% node index.mjs -p 80
{ port: '80' }
% node index.mjs      
You forgot to specify a port number.
{ port: '3000' }
```

(Disclaimer: I am a maintainer of Commander.)

Comment: Thanks @shadownspawn ! I found a workaround by setting `subcommand.opts()[missing_key]` to the answer of my prompt during the `preSubcommand` hook, instead of updating process.argv. Is `setOptionValue` the same thing? 

I had to make my argument a mandatory option instead because I didn't see a way to change the arguments, but having everything as an Option is fine in my case.

Comment: Setting `setOptionValue()` is basically same but more robust, not relying on `opts()` being modifiable.

Comment: Thanks! Is there no way to modify arguments during a `preSubcommand` hook? Modifying/changing options either through `setOptionValue` or setting `process.env[envOfOption]` works fine

Comment: No, you can not modify arguments from a `preSubcommand` hook. There is the potential for modifying the parsed command-arguments in a `preAction` hook, but to be clear it is not a tested use case.